# How to query by count and condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data set full of customers. I am trying to filter the data by those who bought 5 or more items, and then keeping the list of customers who bought 2 specific items.

*Edit-The dataframe looks like this

| CUS_ID | ITEM | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | A | 1996/06/09 |
| 1001 | B | 1999/03/24 |
| 1002 | B | 1999/03/24 |
| 1002 | C | 1999/03/24 |
| 1002 | A | 1999/03/24 |
| 1002 | D | 1999/03/24 |
| 1002 | E | 1999/03/24 |
| 1002 | F | 1999/03/24 |

I use the following

```
df1.groupby('CUS_ID').filter(lambda x: x['CUS_ID'].count()>4)
df1.query('ITEM=="A" or ITEM=="B"')
```

While it does satisfy the first part of the query, the 2nd part obviously just keeps the customer entries with those 2 items but gets rid of the entries of the other items they buy. Is there any way to adjust the query to keep them ? Thanks !

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow (or SO). It's good practice to put a small part of your dataframe.

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos Apologies, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, less good from the one provided by @ezrael:

First, find the customers with the products you want, and store them to another dataframe.

```py
customers = df[(df['ITEM']=='A') | (df['ITEM']=='B')]
```

Then, keep the unique names of them, into a list.

```py
customers = who['CUS_ID'].unique().tolist()
```

Finally, keep the rows from the first dataframe, where the customers are inside.

```py
df = df[df['CUS_ID'].isin(customers)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it did exactly what I needed and I understood what each step is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If need all groups with `A` or `B` values use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df[df['ITEM'].isin(['A','B']).groupby(df['CUS_ID']).transform('any')]
```